# Why the category of CW-complexes is not stable?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

I am studying homotopy theory and I would like to understand better what it means for a category to be **stable**.

For instance, the book I'm studying says that

"the categories **CW∗** and **CCh+** have very similar
homotopical properties. On the other hand, there is a primary difference between them: while
in both we have canonical reduced suspension functor **Σ** and loop space functor **Ω**, the cochain
complex are “stable” under these functors while CW-complexes are not",

where **CW∗** is the category of CW-complexes and **CCh+** is the category of cochain complexes over some communtative ring.

I don't know a lot about classical algebraic topology (I went directly to the higher categorical approach). Thus, it would be quite helpful if someone explained the above statement to me.

Comment: $CW_*$ presumably means the category *pointed* CW complexes. The loop space of a CW complex is unlikely to be a CW complex itself, so maybe $CW_*$ means 'full subcategory of $Top_*$ on the spaces pointed homotopy equivalent to CW complexes'?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Well then both are *stable under the functors*, but stable also has a higher categorical meaning, is that what you're interested in ?

Comment: The meaning is probably simply that $\Sigma$ is an equivalence for chain complexes but not for spaces.

Comment: Fibre and cofibre sequences do not coincide in $CW_*$. Equivalently, homotopy pushouts and pullbacks do not coincide in $CW_*$.